# How to use slick slider to slide a text and an image together?

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to slide a group of text and image together. Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="bottom_slider">
   <div class="bottom_slider_slick">
      <p>
         <span class="bottom_slider_slick_span_title"> asdasd</span> 
          <br /><br />asdasd
       </p>
       <img class="bottom_slider_image" src="Images/bottom_slider_img.png"/>                                    
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_slider_slick">
       <p>
           <span class="bottom_slider_slick_span_title"> asd</span>
           <br /><br />asdfg
        </p>
        <img class="bottom_slider_image"  src="Images/bottom_slider_img.png"/>                                  
     </div>
 </div>
```

And this is the picture that shows how it looks like befofe using slick slider :

Before Slider
[image: Before Slider]

However when I used this code :

```
$(".bottom_slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
});
```

It does not work. It looks like this :

After Slick
[image: After Slick]
What am i doing wrong ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `slidesToShow:2` or is this a setting for how many should show at once? (just a shot in the dark)

Comment: it defines how many slide will be shown together (if i do it 2 it will slide 2 by 2 )

Comment: Do you have something in the javascript console ?

Comment: use `inspect element` to see if the image element is there at all (maybe its positioned outside the window or below some other element)

Comment: **[`Your code works fine`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3z5oqgzs/)**

Comment: Ok i just recognize that the problem was assigning the position of the image as absolute. I have changed it and it works fine. Thanks for your interest.